# MPAndroidChart - Round edge candle stick chart

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart, rounded-corners

I am trying to create a chart like below for android application using Mpchart, I'm using Candle Stick chart.

Expected output

[image]

Actual output

[image]

Can anyone suggest me what I should do.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far?